# Instantiating Request in Controller in Kohana 3.3

Tags: request, kohana, kohana-3.3

While upgrading my own module to work with latest Kohana (3.3) I found malfunction in my scenario. I use template driven schema in my app (My Controllers extend Controller_Theme). But for AJAX calls I used in version 3.2 separate Controller which extends just Controller. I had to instantiate Request object in this controller for access passed variables via POST or GET in Rquest object. I did it in __construct() method:

```
class Controller_Ajax extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->request = Request::current();    
    }

    public function action_myaction()
    {
        if($this->is_ajax())
        {
            $url = $this->request->post('url');
            $text = $this->request->post('text');
        }   
    }
}
```

In myaction() method I can access posted variables like this. 
But this does not work anymore in Kohana 3.3. I always get this error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function action() on a non-object
SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Controller.php [ 73 ]
68  {
69      // Execute the "before action" method
70      $this->before();
71      
72      // Determine the action to use
73      $action = 'action_'.$this->request->action();
74 
75      // If the action doesn't exist, it's a 404
76      if ( ! method_exists($this, $action))
77      {
78          throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
```

I am sure I have routes set up correctly. I didn't found any changes in migration document from 3.2 to 3.3 about Request object. Or did I missed something?

Comment: `$this->request = Request::current();` - why do you need to do this? It should be done automatically by the framework, and I don't think it's guaranteed that `Request::current` is going to be available at this stage (in the constructor). Otherwise, if you really have to do it, try to put it inside `public function before() {}`

Comment: `__construct()` method - here was the problem. When it stays in my Controller, Request object is not constructed. When I replace it with `before()` method as You mentioned, everything is correct. And Yes, `$this->req = Request::current()` can be omitted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Both request and response are initialised by default in the `Controller` class (see below code), so there shouldn't be need to override it's constructor. Try to remove your constructor and if that doesn't help, then your routing is messed up.

```
abstract class Kohana_Controller {

    /**
     * @var  Request  Request that created the controller
     */
    public $request;

    /**
     * @var  Response The response that will be returned from controller
     */
    public $response;

    /**
     * Creates a new controller instance. Each controller must be constructed
     * with the request object that created it.
     *
     * @param   Request   $request  Request that created the controller
     * @param   Response  $response The request's response
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Assign the request to the controller
        $this->request = $request;

        // Assign a response to the controller
        $this->response = $response;
    }
```